# MSOLEDBSQL IDbInitialize::Initialize() Always Returns E_FAIL

Tags: c++, sql-server, oledb

I'm using the following environment for development:

1. Server: SQL Express on Windows 10
2. Version: 15.0.2101.7
3. Instance Name: MYSURFACE\SQLEXPRESS
4. OLE DB Version: 19.3

The goal is to connect to the DB from my C++ code using the aforementioned MSOLEDBSQL driver. Despite my best attempts, I'm not able to connect to the database. The returned value is always E_FAIL and the reason is "**Client unable to establish connection.**" I have also tried several other combinations of different user IDs and password, trusted connection, etc. The result is always the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
void InitializeEnvironment()
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
IDBInitialize* initializer = nullptr;
IDBProperties* propertySetter = nullptr;
DBPROP props[1];
LPCWSTR lpwszProviderString = L"Server=MYSURFACE\\SQLEXPRESS;"   
L"Database=RefDb_DEV;"
L"Trusted_Connection=yes";
//L"UID=serviceusr;"
//L"PWD=myoldpassword;";
DBPROPSET* prgPropertySets = nullptr;
ULONG cPropertySets = 0;
 
hr = CoInitialize(nullptr);
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MSOLEDBSQL19, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IDBProperties), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&propertySetter));
 
// set provider string
props[0].dwPropertyID = DBPROP_INIT_PROVIDERSTRING;
props[0].dwOptions = DBPROPOPTIONS_REQUIRED;
props[0].colid = DB_NULLID;
VariantInit(&(props[0].vValue));
V_VT(&(props[0].vValue)) = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&(props[0].vValue)) = SysAllocString(lpwszProviderString);
 
{ // set the property to the property set
DBPROPSET PropertySet[1] = {};
PropertySet[0].rgProperties = &props[0];
PropertySet[0].cProperties = 1;
PropertySet[0].guidPropertySet = DBPROPSET_DBINIT;
 
// set properties and connect to server
hr = propertySetter->SetProperties(sizeof(PropertySet) / sizeof(DBPROPSET), PropertySet);
}
 
hr = propertySetter->QueryInterface<IDBInitialize>(&initializer);
//********This is the call that always fails**********
hr = initializer->Initialize();
//*****************************************
if (hr != S_OK)
{
IErrorInfo* errorInfo = nullptr;
hr = GetErrorInfo(0, &errorInfo);
if (hr == S_OK)
{
BSTR errorDesc, source;
errorInfo->GetDescription(&errorDesc);
errorInfo->GetSource(&source);
}
}
 
// get properties
DBPROPIDSET rgDBPropIDSet[1] = {};
 
DBPROPID rgDBPropID[2] = {};
rgDBPropID[0] = SSPROP_INTEGRATEDAUTHENTICATIONMETHOD;
rgDBPropID[1] = SSPROP_MUTUALLYAUTHENTICATED;
 
rgDBPropIDSet[0].rgPropertyIDs = &rgDBPropID[0];
rgDBPropIDSet[0].cPropertyIDs = 2;
rgDBPropIDSet[0].guidPropertySet = DBPROPSET_SQLSERVERDATASOURCEINFO;
hr = propertySetter->GetProperties(1, rgDBPropIDSet, &cPropertySets, &prgPropertySets);
wprintf(L"Authentication method: %s\r\n", V_BSTR(&(prgPropertySets[0].rgProperties[0].vValue)));
wprintf(L"Mutually authenticated: %s\r\n",
(V_BOOL(&(prgPropertySets[0].rgProperties[1].vValue)) == VARIANT_TRUE) ? L"yes" : L"no");
}
```

I have also tried some wrong connection string keyword (e.g., "User ID=..." instead of "UID=..."). That results in a different error, but the minute I get the string right, it's always E_FAIL with that description. Also, on using "Server=(local)" and other combinations, the connection times out after about 10-15 seconds. The amusing thing is that anytime I have all the connection string keywords right, it fails instantly with that message.

Comment: Since OLE DB v19 and later includes breaking changes around Encyption, and the default installations of SQL Server use self-signed certificates, have you tried the simple approach of including `L"Encryption=Optional;"` and/or `L"TrustServerCertificate=yes;"` in your provider string properties? Ref: [Encryption and certificate validation in OLE DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/features/encryption-and-certificate-validation)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, thanks for your response. It finally worked after I tried a few combinations of your suggested keywords. What worked for me was to create a new DB user on my SQL Server (not Windows auth) and then use that along with Encrypt=Optional. The connection string that finally worked was L"Server=MYSURFACE\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RefDb_DEV;UID=genericdbuser;PWD=oledbuser;Encrypt=Optional"

Comment: Just wanted to add: It refused to take Trusted_Connection or TrustServerCertificate. Anytime either of those keywords were used, it returned a "Multi-step OLE DB operation generated errors..." HRESULT along with IErrorInfo desc of "Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'Trusted_Connection'" or ''TrustServerCertificate," as per the case. But getting it to work was a huge step in the right direction. I would still like to get "trusted connection" to work (as it does so seamlessly with ADO.NET in C# or CLI). Let me know if you can think of anything on that front. Thanks again!

Comment: It's worth noting that Trusted Connection and Trust Server Certificate are entirely different controls. Trusted Connection indicates that Active Directory/Kerberos/Windows authentication should be used instead of the SQL Logon-based UID/Username and PWD/Password authentication - when active it uses the authentication token of the currently-running process to authenticate against SQL Server. Trust Server Certificate is used to control whether or not self-signed certificates should be trusted to establish SSL/TLS connections to the target server.

Comment: Any thoughts on why Trusted_Connection refuses to work for me? My SQL Server instance has both, SQL Server and Windows Auth modes, enabled. Also, not sure how different the two are, but "...;Integrated Security=true;..." in an ADO.NET connection string works pretty seamlessly. So, I would expect Trusted_Connection in the OLEDB connection string to work as well, but it fails each time.  Could it be that I'm missing a related keyword(s) in the string when using Trusted_Connection? Can't tell from the documentation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: When using Integrated Security/Trusted Connection the client process uses its Active Directory/Kerberos/Windows authentication token to authenticate with the SQL Server instance. The instance must have a corresponding Windows Logon registered (or a Windows Group containing that logon) for this to work, and the client computer and SQL Server host computer must all be members of the same logon domain. This is a completely different authentication model than SQL Logon, where the client process just provides a username and password which the instance checks against its own, internal, SQL Logons.